# replace all </script> tags with <\/script> in javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, replace, backslash

I need to replace all these tags `</script>` with these tags `</script>`

Before: -> `<script>..code..</script> <script>..code..</script>`

After:  ---> `<script>..code..<\/script> <script>..code..<\/script>`

But this does not work:

```
function myReplace(){
    var X = document.getElementById("demo").innerText;
    var Y = X.replace(/</script>/ig, '<\/script>');
    document.getElementById("demo").innerText = Y;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wG3LG/3/)**

Here's a related **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24988672/document-write-replace-script-tags-with-script)** for a better understanding

Comment: `/</script>/ig` isn't a valid regex. The `/` inside needs escaping. By the way, why are you doing this? Do you *want* to have a bunch of unclosed script tags?

Comment: this won't work because the script tags inside your div (from the demo) are tags - not text. thus your innerText won't contain them.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by that?

Comment: Also... why are you trying to do this? this looks like you are trying to solve a problem you shouldn't have.

Comment: Don't want to repeat what others have already posted. But if you for some reason really need it, then you may have to pickup the value using `innerHTML` and set using `textContent` or `innerText` like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/wG3LG/2/).

Comment: please have a look **[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24988672/document-write-replace-script-tags-with-script)**

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your expression isn't going to work. Your slashes aren't being escaped properly.  Try this.

```
function myReplace(){
   var X = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML;
   var Y = X.replace(/<\/script>/ig, "<\\\/script>");
   document.getElementById("demo").innerText = Y;
}
```

I also found a [good article](https://www.wwco.com/~wls/blog/2007/04/25/using-script-in-a-javascript-literal/) about how to do this and why. They go to the extent of escaping your < and > sign's, but I believe escaping your your forward slashes is the most important.

Comment: Updated to include global.

Comment: please have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24988672/document-write-replace-script-tags-with-script)

Comment: Also this answer does solve for the question asked. You asked how to replace </script tags with <\/script>. Neither your demo or your code indicate that you would be running this from within a </script> tag. This solution does in fact work and can be seen here [link](http://jsfiddle.net/wG3LG/5/)

Comment: Great answer , saved my time :)